# How to detect if input string has only one number in Ruby

Tags: ruby

As I wrote in the title, I want to find if a string input consists of only one number.

Examples are

```
222 # true
33333 # true
22334 # false
556677 # false
```

I thought to use String#reverse but it fails with `556677`.

```
if input == input.reverse
  # do something
end
```

What is the best way?

Comment: Probably a good candidate for [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex like...

```
^(\d)\1*$
```

For example, this code...

```
strs = ['11211', '1', '111', '2222', '212']

strs.each {|str|
    puts /^(\d)\1*$/.match(str)
}
```

...produces...

```
1 
111 
2222
```

[Fiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/2929e).

Comment: That's how I'd do it, though I might write `puts str[/^(\d)\1*$/]`.

Comment: Good suggestion, I haven't written any Ruby for some time. :)

Answer (score 6):

Non-regex solution:

```
input.chars.uniq.size == 1
"222".chars.uniq.size == 1 #=> true
"556677".chars.uniq.size == 1 #=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [String#squeeze](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-squeeze) followed by [String#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with a regex that matches a string consisting of a single digit:

```
"2222".squeeze[/^\d$/] #=> 2
"5566".squeeze[/^\d$/] #=> nil
"333a".squeeze[/^\d$/] #=> nil
"aaaa".squeeze[/^\d$/] #=> nil
```

The return value is either `nil` (falsy) or the unique digit (truey).

This is just a fun answer.  In real life, I'd do it the way @alex has.